# Redirect from sprinboot to a specific external URL

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing an application that, after logging in through a service, calls my Spring Boot backend and redirects to the URL where my Angular application is exposed.

This is my controller:

```
@Path("/login")
@Controller
public interface LoginApi  {
    @POST
    @Consumes({ "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
    RedirectView login(@FormParam(value = "idToken") String idToken, @FormParam(value = "timestamp")  String timestamp, @FormParam(value = "mac")  String mac, @Context SecurityContext securityContext, @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders , @Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest);
}
```

This is the implementation:

```
@Component
public class LoginApiImpl implements LoginApi {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginApiImpl.class);

  @Override
    public RedirectView login(String idToken, String timestamp, String mac,
                          @Context SecurityContext securityContext,
                          @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
                          @Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest){
        LOG.info("idToken: " + idToken + " timestamp: " + timestamp + " mac: " + mac);
        return new RedirectView("www.google.com") ;
}
```

When I invoke the service, it returns this error: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView of media type: application/octet-stream

I expect the request to be sent to the URL I am providing from Spring Boot.

Comment: Does adding tis `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) ` helps?

Comment: Using separate interface for @RestController is an overshoot imo.

Comment: Wait, is it Jersey/reasteasy or something?

Comment: Can you provide or post RedirectView code?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html

Comment: I bet it would work in SpringMVC sine it is a part of it .....

Comment: I think, jackson or whatever library that convert message to object or json cant deserialize this type

Comment: and You don't use @ResponseBody for response

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solved it in the following way:

```
@Component
public class LoginApiImpl implements LoginApi {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginApiImpl.class);

  @Override
    public Response login(String idToken, String timestamp, String mac,
                              @Context SecurityContext securityContext,
                              @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
                              @Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest){
        RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
        return  Response.seeOther(UriBuilder.fromUri("https://www.google.com").build()).build();
    }
```